# Clip polygons with other polygons based on matching attributes

Tags: qgis, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, clip, fields-attributes

I have two shapefiles, one which contains event locations and the the other of which represents regions where events take place.

- **Events** polygons with `year` and `region_name` attributes
- **Regions** polygons, which also have `year` and `region_name` attributes

The Event polygons sometimes extend beyond their proper Region.  Regions sometimes change boundaries, which is why they also have a `year` attribute.  **I would like to clip each Event polygon using the appropriate Region polygon, i.e. the one with matching `year` and `region_name` attributes.**  Here is an image I made to illustrate the basic idea:

[image: Illustration of Event polygons being clipped by the appropriate Region polygons]

Some solutions I've tried but which have been unsatisfactory:

- Doing it manually (selecting each event and region by hand and clipping them), which seems unnecessarily tedious
- Using *Select By Location* to isolate the Events in each Region, which still requires working with each selection manually
- Using *Intersect*, which 1) leaves lots of event "remnants" outside their proper regions and 2) "oversplits" by dividing all Event polygons by all Region polygons, regardless of year

Note: I use both QGIS 1.8 and ArcMap 10.1.  I can't install extensions for ArcGIS (I don't have administrative access) but I can use Python scripts.

Comment: You say you have "groups of shapefiles". Is there a separate shapefile for 1990 events and 1991 events? How about regions: are they split into annual shapefiles?

Comment: @GeoKevin Sorry, I wasn't clear! I have only two shapefiles: one for Events and one for Regions.  I'll edit the post accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ArcMap, you could use python to run nested search cursors. For example:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("region shapefile location", "Regions")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("event shapefile location", "Events")

out_features = "name and location for output clips"
out_count = 0

r_rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(Regions)
for r_row in r_rows:
  r_name = r_row.region_name
  r_year = r_row.year
  e_rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(Events)
  for e_row in e_rows:
    e_name = e_row.region_name
    e_year = e_row.year
    if r_name == e_name and r_year == e_year:
      out_count += 1
      out_features = out_features + str(out_count)
      query = "\"region_name\" = '" + r_name + "'"
      arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Regions, "", query)
      arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Events, "ADD_TO_SELECTION", query)
      arcpy.Clip_analysis(Events, Regions, out_features)
  del e_row, e_rows
del r_row, r_rows
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also do this in ArcMap using ModelBuilder.

String together these tools:

- [Iterate Feature Selection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Iterate_Feature_Selection/00400000000s000000/) - Use Region Name and Year as Group Fields
- [Calculate Value](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Calculate_Value/004000000004000000/) - Calculate the expression to use to select an event (arcpy snippet) - Feed the expression into the select tool
- [Select](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Select/000800000005000000/) - For each iteration, it selects the events that correspond to the region/year combo
- [Clip](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Clip/000800000004000000/) - Clips the Events by Region based on Region Name/Year combination
- [Delete](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Delete/001700000052000000/) - Deletes the temporary select feature after the model executes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I accepted Krauser's because I'm more comfortable with Python than ModelBuilder, but this helps make the structure of the process clearer.